# PHP fwrite function new line

Tags: php, newline, fwrite

i have this code:

```
//This line is for the input that i've looped above my code, it's a URL
$textAr[$i] = str_replace("\r\n","", $textAr[$i]);

//This is for implode purposes
$finalArray = array($textAr[$i], $m1, $m2, $m3, $m4, $m5, $m6);

//When i echo this variable, $test, the URL is in the line along with the implode arrays
$test = implode($finalArray, "***");
echo $test."\n";

//This is for writing into my text file
fwrite($sitesTxt, implode($finalArray, "***")."\n");
```

I'm having the kind of error where after i input a 3 URLs, the first and second URL has new line after i write in the file, but the last URL I've input is in line along with the imploded arrays. I've even trimmed the $textArr, but i keep getting the new lines.

Expected output:

```
https://docs.google.com***false***false***false***false***false***false***
https://stackoverflow.com***false***false***false***false***false***false***
https://stackexchange.com***false***false***false***false***false***false***
```

Output i'm getting at the txt file:

```
https://docs.google.com
***false***false***false***false***false***false***
https://stackoverflow.com
***false***false***false***false***false***false***
https://stackexchange.com***false***false***false***false***false***false***
```

Comment: Post your full code please (include loop, example data)

Comment: can you tell me what is the `$textArr[$i]`? you can echo it? or just give example data for that

Comment: My code is garbage. It's for noobs. Anyway, i've accepted RichGold's solution, it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your system, your lines may not end with a \r\n combination, but perhaps just \r.

I suggest either change str_replace to:

```
$textAr[$i] = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"", $textAr[$i]);
```

Or, change the array:

```
$finalArray = array(trim($textAr[$i]), $m1, $m2, $m3, $m4, $m5, $m6);
```

Incidentally, although it will work, your implode parameters are reversed:

```
$test = implode("***", $finalArray);
```

Comment: I've added trim just like you've said and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP_EOL constant for 'break-line' character. Because the break-line character in DOS is `\r\n`, but in *nix, it's just `\n`.
So, you replace the first line to

`$textAr[$i] = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $textAr[$i]);`